# Unhandled Exception with OCaml 5.0.0~beta1

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-5

I'm inconsistently getting this error in a first experiment with OCaml 5.0.0~beta1:

> Fatal error: exception Stdlib.Effect.Unhandled(Domainslib__Task.Wait(_, _))

My setup:

1. Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
2. Debian 10 (buster)
3. opam version 2.1.3 installed as binary from [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)
4. opam switch: "→  5.0.0~beta1  ocaml-base-compiler.5.0.0~beta1  5.0.0~beta1"

After a quick read of [this tutorial](https://github.com/ocaml-multicore/parallel-programming-in-multicore-ocaml), I copied the parallel_matrix_multiply function and added some code in the end just to use it:

```
open Domainslib

let parallel_matrix_multiply pool a b =
  let i_n = Array.length a in
  let j_n = Array.length b.(0) in
  let k_n = Array.length b in
  let res = Array.make_matrix i_n j_n 0 in

  Task.parallel_for pool ~start:0 ~finish:(i_n - 1) ~body:(fun i ->
    for j = 0 to j_n - 1 do
      for k = 0 to k_n - 1 do
        res.(i).(j) <- res.(i).(j) + a.(i).(k) * b.(k).(j)
      done
    done);
  res ;;

let pool = Task.setup_pool ~num_domains:3 () in
let a = Array.make_matrix 2 2 1 in
let b = Array.make_matrix 2 2 2 in
let c = parallel_matrix_multiply pool a b in
for i = 0 to 1 do
        for j = 0 to 1 do
          Printf.printf "%d " c.(i).(j)
        done;
        print_char '\n'
done;;
```

I then compile it with no errors with

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -package domainslib parallel_for.ml
```

and then comes the problem: executing the generated `a.out` file sometimes (rarely) prints the expected output

```
4 4 
4 4
```

but usually ends with the error mentioned earlier:

```
Fatal error: exception Stdlib.Effect.Unhandled(Domainslib__Task.Wait(_, _))
```

Sorry if I am making some trivial mistake, but I can't understand what is going on, especially given that the error happens inconsistently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parallel_matrix_multiply` computation is running outside of the Domainslib scheduler, thus whenever a task yields to the scheduler, the `Wait` effect is unhandled and transformed into a `Effect.Unhandled` exception.
The solution is to run the parallel computation within `Task.run`:

```
...
let c = Task.run pool (fun () -> parallel_matrix_multiply pool a b) in
...
```